# SIGABRT crash in Samsung Devices

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, sigabrt

Android Application crashes as soon as it goes in background with this error.

> A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 31234 (RenderThread)

Below is the stack trace on developer console, there is no detailed log in stack trace:

```
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** 
pid: 0, tid: 0 >>> com.github.angads25 <<<

backtrace:   
#00  pc 000000000004ae00  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
#01  pc 0000000000048593  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+34)   
#02  pc 000000000001de2d  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+10)   
#03  pc 0000000000019531  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_android_abort+34)   
#04  pc 0000000000017170  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
#05  pc 000000000000c613  /system/lib/libcutils.so (__android_log_assert+114) 
#06  pc 000000000003cf75  /system/lib/libhwui.so
#07  pc 00000000000271e3  /system/lib/libhwui.so
#08  pc 00000000000257c1  /system/lib/libhwui.so
#09  pc 0000000000028231  /system/lib/libhwui.so
#10  pc 0000000000028ad3  /system/lib/libhwui.so
#11  pc 0000000000029b01  /system/lib/libhwui.so (_ZN7android10uirenderer12renderthread12RenderThread10threadLoopEv+80)
#12  pc 000000000000e401  /system/lib/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Thread11_threadLoopEPv+144)
#13  pc 000000000006a925  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZN7android14AndroidRuntime15javaThreadShellEPv+80)
#14  pc 0000000000048063  /system/lib/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+22)  
#15  pc 000000000001a1b1  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+6)
```

The crash is very specific to only following Samsung devices and for Android 7.0.0:

```
Galaxy J7 Neo (j7velte)     200 40.5%
Galaxy J7(2016) (j7xelte)   181 36.6%
Galaxy J5 Prime (on5xelte)  39  7.9%
Galaxy A5(2016) (a5xelte)   25  5.1%
Galaxy J7 (j7y17lte)        18  3.6%
Galaxy J7 Prime (on7xelte)  14  2.8%
Galaxy A3(2016) (a3xelte)   12  2.4%
Galaxy J7 Max (j7maxlte)    2   0.4%
Galaxy On8 (j7xlte)         2   0.4%
Galaxy A7(2016) (a7xelte)   1   0.2%
```